# JDatechooser is not working properly in searching between columns

Tags: java

I am facing a problem with jdatechooser while i used to search data between columns via jdatechooser..The problem is when I search the data,it shows the correct data but it also shows the data which I dont want. the following is my error message picture.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tke7N.png)

[image: wrong-output]

you can see that I want to search the data between 1 november to 7 november but it shows the last two transactions also.
 The following is my code

```
private void okActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try
    {
        String sql="select * from Bill_Ledger where Date >=(?) and Date <=(?)";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1,((JTextField)fromdate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
        pst.setString(2,((JTextField)todate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
        rs=pst.executeQuery();


        medic_table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            pst.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: are you using the `JDateChooser` from `JCalendar` library?

Comment: yes..actually i didn't import the library package in my code..I just simply dragged and droped

Answer (score 0):

What I would do if I were you is to first print out on the console what date string you are placing into SQL like this:

```
System.out.println("From date: "+pst.setString(1,((JTextField)fromdate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText()));

System.out.println("To date: "+pst.setString(2,((JTextField)todate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
```

and later on, I would try to execute given sql by hand in external tool (like mysql workbench or simple CLI) and check if I get the desired results.

```
select * from Bill_Ledger where Date >=fromDate and Date <=toDate
```

My best bet right now, is that date string are formatted in bad way (in database terms). This is little bit hard to find, because mysql willl not complain about bad date format.

Correct format for queries should be like `'yyyy-MM-dd'`